# What happen with LiveData after delay

Tags: android, android-livedata

Here is my code :

`HomeFragment`

```
...

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    homeViewModel.myTest.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        Log.d(TAG, "myTest=$it")
    }

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        homeViewModel.doSomethingForMyTest()
    }

}
...
```

`HomeViewModel`

```
...

private val _myTest = MutableLiveData<String>()
val myTest: LiveData<String> = _myTest

fun doSomethingForMyTest() {
    Log.i(TAG, "doSomethingForMyTest start: ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
    (1..3).forEach {
        _myTest.value = it.toString()
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "doSomethingForMyTest end: ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
}

...
```

`log` :

```
I/HomeViewModel: doSomethingForMyTest start: 1628586904976
I/HomeViewModel: doSomethingForMyTest end: 1628586904977
D/HomeFragment: myTest=3
```

---

If add delay before I call the function, like this :

`HomeFragment`

```
...

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    homeViewModel.myTest.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        Log.d(TAG, "myTest=$it")
    }
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        delay(1)
        homeViewModel.doSomethingForMyTest()
    }
}

...
```

`log` :

```
I/HomeViewModel: doSomethingForMyTest start: 1628587129413
D/HomeFragment: myTest=1
D/HomeFragment: myTest=2
D/HomeFragment: myTest=3
I/HomeViewModel: doSomethingForMyTest end: 1628587129414
```

---

As you can see, I don’t know the difference...

Why logs different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you're missing:

[`viewLifecycleOwner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getViewLifecycleOwner()) - during `onViewCreated` it's still in the `INITIALIZED` state so your liveData observer will not receive updates until fragment is moved to `STARTED` state.

[`lifecycleScope`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/LifecycleCoroutineScope) - it is backed by `Dispatchers.Main.immediate` which means `launch` is executed immediately when you're already in the right context (ui thread) until first suspending call.

In first case you add observer then your three updates run immediately but observer is not active yet so it only receives the last value when fragments `viewLifecycleOwner` moves to `STARTED` state.

In second case `delay` is a suspending point so your `launch` cannot execute in-line. Since `lifecycleScope` is backed by `Dispatchers.Main` call has to be delayed until next ui-thread cycle during which fragment is already in `STARTED` state so your observer is active and it receives each update in real time.

Comment: Thanks, I figure out how `observe` method work.  
"The observer will only receive events if the owner is in Lifecycle.State.STARTED or Lifecycle.State.RESUMED state (active)."  
And the `delay`, maybe I should read more document of coroutines.